# Generate java classes from a JSON schema

Tags: json, code-generation, jsonschema

I would like to generate JAVA classes from a given JSON Schema [draft 4 version](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04)

I evaluated couple of tools and [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo) was found to be useful. But it supports json schema draft-3 version only(although json schema draft 4 is in their roadmap).

Can anyone suggest me a tool or a way to generate java classes from a json schema (compliant to json schema draft4)
?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u find solution? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

You might try [cog](https://github.com/ktonon/cog), a general purpose code generator written in Ruby. I put a simple project on github called [json2java](https://github.com/ktonon/json2java) which demonstrates how cog might be used to generate Java classes from json data.

Not sure exactly what you want to do, but here is what I assumed. The json data would look something like this

```
{
    "classname": "Sample",
    "methods": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "rtype": "void",
            "params": [
                {
                    "name": "arg1",
                    "type": "int"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "rtype": "int",
            "params": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And the corresponding Java class would look something like this

```
public class Sample {

    void foo(int arg1) {
// keep: foo {
        // While the interface in this example is generated,
        // the method bodies are preserved between multiple invocations
        // of the generator.

        // It doesn't have to be done this way, the method bodies can be
        // generated aswell, all depends on what your json data encodes
// keep: }
    }

    int bar() {
// keep: bar {
        return 1;
// keep: }
    }

}
```

If you want to try cog, install it like this `gem install cog`, and run generators like this `cog gen`. Check out the cog homepage for documentation.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.I am looking to generate java classes using maven from a json "schema"(not json string) that complies withe json schema draft 4 version.I will look into the tool you have suggested , if it helps me.

Comment: Yes, the question wasn't parsing json alone, but generating a class using the JSON Schema, which is a formal specification of the structure of the JSON and supports validation, etc.